# Preventing search engines to crawl on specific folders

Tags: search-engines, robots.txt

I have set the robot.txt of my website as follow after seeing lots of errors in google's webmaster tools. Mainly because of the Smarty template files. So I changed my robots file as follow:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /templates_c
```

My question is, in the second line I allow every folder, and in the third line I disallow `/templates_c` folder. So which case will be evaluated by the robots? I mean if I am allowing everything but next line disallow one folder, what will be the result?

Or should I add any folders that I want to be searched to `Allow` and then call `Disallow`?

Comment: "robot.txt" - I assume this is a typo, but it should be "robots.txt" (with an "s")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You really only need the disallow. Search engine crawlers will automatically assume they are allowed everywhere that isn't disallowed.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /templates_c
```

But to answer your question, according to Google:

> At a group-member level, in particular for allow and disallow
>   directives, the most specific rule based on the length of the [path]
>   entry will trump the less specific (shorter) rule. The order of
>   precedence for rules with wildcards is undefined.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)

Thus, your current rules *should* work as intended for properly behaving bots (i.e. allowed everywhere but the templates_c directory).

Note: `Disallow: /templates_c` will disallow all files and folders in the root that contain that within their name. If you intended to disallow only the specific `templates_c` directory, add a trailing slash: `Disallow: /templates_c/`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry if this is wrong, I'm not familiar with the Smarty template engine.

Does the template_c folder have to be publicly accessible at all? I imagine that Smarty does use functions like `include()` to fetch the template code, so you could easily create a .htaccess file in the template_c folder that disallows access to any visitor. It would look like this:

```
DENY FROM ALL
```