# Rules for robots.txt file to exclude a whole subdomain from google's search results

Tags: robots.txt

In my website's root folder i already have a robots.txt file with some rules for the domain name www.example.com.

My website is multilingual so i have setup with drupal de.example.com, fr.example.com & es.example.com

I want to **exclude the subdomain** es.example.com from google's search results.

Because there is only one root, will the following rules work in the **only one robots.txt**?

```
User-agent: *  
Disallow: es.example.com/
```

**EDIT:**
I have updated the robots.txt and submitted to Google's webmasters tools (robots.txt Tester).
It didn't gave me any errors or warnings, so i will wait for the results!

Comment: You should also find [Preventing search engines to crawl on specific folders](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42661/preventing-search-engines-to-crawl-on-specific-folders) helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude it?

Comment: @dasickle, because it is not as it should be & to fix the content it will take more that 8 months!

Comment: @kanenas.net so you no longer going to have es.example.com at all?

Comment: @bybe, i am not sure why you marked the question as a duplicate. Also i can't find the answer to my question in the thread you suggested.

Comment: `i am not sure why you marked the question as a duplicate` Your not looking hard enough then. Update your robots on both domains  `Disallow: /es.example.com/` in `www.main-domain.com/robots.txt` and add `Disallow: /` in `es.example.com/robots.txt`

Comment: You can also find [300+ robots.txt related questions here.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5Brobots.txt%5D%20is%3aquestion)

Comment: @bybe, i can not have a **es.example.com/robots.txt**, so i will just change this `Disallow: /es.example.com/` in **www.main-domain.com/robots.txt**. Thanks!

Comment: Using `Disallow: /es.example.com/`  in `www.main-domain.com/robots.txt` will only block `www.main-domain.com/es.example.com/` if you want to block `http://es.main-domain.com` you must have `http://es.main-domain.com/robots.txt` or use [meta noindex](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in the HTML of every page on your sub domain. You can find all these kind of information in the hundreds of already made questions and answers on the site, or alternatively visit [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) to discuss this further.